# Can't create Keycloak 17.0.0 admin user

Tags: keycloak

I installed Keycloak 17.0.0 but not able to create admin user. I followed this [document](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-zip).
When I access Keycloak page, it is showing "you need local access to create the initial admin user". Screenshot is here - [Keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtGfK.png). Also I didn't find the add-user-keycloak script in Keycloak 17.0.0. I am quite new to this. Can anyone help on how to create the initial admin user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The add-user script is part of the previous release of keycloak.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, someone far cleverer than I figured this out:

```
export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
sudo -E bin/kc.sh start-dev
```

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10262

But don't use admin/admin of course...

Answer (score 1):

I to have been trying to play around with `Keycloak 17`, and have found it far from easy to get it to work as I expected.

I am trying to get it work on remote server,where its impossible to login on localhost.  To create the admin user I followed the information in the Keycloak document at [KeyCloak documents](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/), see the section called `Creating the first administrator`

You set the following envronmental variables

> export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN='username'
> export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD='password'
> bin/kc.[sh|bat] start

Were username and password are strings for username and password.

Another problem I had was getting `Keycloak` to work on my  server haggis on port 8085.  My solution was to invoke it as follows.

> ./kc.sh start-dev --http-port=8085 --http-host=haggis --db-url-host=haggis --db-username=kc --hostname=haggis:8085 --hostname-admin=haggis:8085 --hostname-strict-backchannel=true --db-url-database=postgresql --db-username='kcuser'

This command line instructs `Keycloak` to start up on the server `haggis`, at port 8085, using a `postgres` database with a database user called `kcuser` in development  mode.

My largest problem was working out that you had to include the port number in the hostname style arguments.

Once everything is working you can invoke it as

> http://haggis:8085/admin/master/console/#/realms/master